# How can i extract labels from file name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some files inside the training folder and filenames are train0947.txt, train038.txt, test0498.txt, and test032.txt. I would like to get my output as shown below. I have done a similar task in my past but the filenames have some kind of split criteria like _ or, say train_0947.txt and It was easy to split but now it is a little bit hard for me to split. Could someone help me on how to achieve such output?

```
file           class
train0947.txt  train
train038.txt   train
test0498.txt   test
test032.txt    test
```

My code:

```
em = glob("/home/xx/PycharmProjects/Dat/main/training/*.txt")
train_em = []
train_class = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(em))):
    # creating the image name
    train_em.append(em[i].split('/')[7])
    # creating the class of image
    train_class.append(em[i].split('/')[7].split('')[0]) --> here what split i should use?

# storing the images and their class in a dataframe
train_data = pd.DataFrame()
train_data['em'] = train_em
train_data['class'] = train_class
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try extract all the `nondigits` that are immediately followed by `digits`.

In short: `v(?=w)` - also known as lookahead assertion. Match `v` only if it is followed by `w`.

Code below:

```
df['class']=df['file'].str.extract('(\D+(?=\d))')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to filter the files you are interested into and extract their types (test or train):

```py
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

filename_regex = re.compile(r'^(train|test)(?:\d+)\.txt$')

root_folder = "/home/xx/PycharmProjects/Dat/main/training"
train_em, train_class = [], []
for filename in next(os.walk(root_folder))[2]:
    m  = filename_regex.match(filename)
    if m is None:
        continue

    # creating the image name
    train_em.append(filename)
    # creating the class of image
    train_class.append(m.groups()[0])

# storing the images and their class in a dataframe
train_data = pd.DataFrame()
train_data['em'] = train_em
train_data['class'] = train_class
```

Comment: i get error saying stop iteration at for loop

Comment: It means that `root_folder` does not contain any file: have you checked that the path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your files are either `train` or `test`:

```
import glob


def classify_file(dir):
    files = {}
    for file in glob.glob(f"{dir}//*.txt"):
        if "train" in file:
            files[file] = "train"
        elif "test" in file:
            files[file] = "test"
        else:
            files[file] = "Other"

    return files
```